# Фамилия Романовы

Tags: этимология, ономастика

Может, это вопрос больше из истории, чем из русского языка, но известно ли происхождение царской фамилии Романовы? Ясно, что они были из бояр, но каковы самые корни фамилии?

Answer (score 1):

***Рома́нов*** — фамилия, образованная как отчество от крестильного имени Роман (греч. Ρωμανός, лат. Romanus — римский). Женская форма — Романова.